# How to check if a Javascript variable is defined before invoking it

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am using Cordova GA plugin to track events, but when testing in my browser I keep getting:

> ReferenceError: plugin is not defined

I tried many ways to check if the plugin has been defined, but it still throws this error. How can I properly check if the plugin has been defined before I invoke the function?

Comment: Btw take a look at this http://emulate.phonegap.com/

Answer (score 5):

To check if a JavaScript variable is undefined you can use

```
if (typeof myVariable === 'undefined') {
  console.log('The variable is undefined.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply put a check before running your code:

```js
if (window.plugin) {//I had assume that `plugin` is in global scope
  alert('plugin');
} else {
  alert('no plugin');
}
```

Using `typeof`

```js
if('undefined' === typeof plugin) {
  alert('no plugin');
} else {
  alert('plugin ...');
}
```